# Specific excel shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007, shortcuts

I am trying to create specific keyboard shortcuts with only one key in Excel 2007. For example:

- when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I want to move one cell left and then one cell down
- and when I press  <kbd>*</kbd>  to move one cell right

I'm trying to do this with macros, but Excel only lets me use keyboard combinations -- e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Is it posible to create these shortcuts with only one key in Excel 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `Autohotkey` to achieve this.
It's a free automation and scripting utility for windows and you can get it from here:
http://www.autohotkey.com/download/

You can combine `IfWinActive` with a `hotkey` to achieve your requirements.
I am writing the script for you but I would encourage you to explore and learn the tool so that you can use for other purposes as well.

This is the script:

```
Enter::
IfWinActive Microsoft Excel
    Send {Enter}{Left}
return
```

P.S. I would recommend against assigning `*` as hotkey.
That way, you will not be able type `*` in Excel

Comment: it is weird, I know :), but I need it for my work...I will try the up solution.Thanks

Comment: tumchaaditya your solution works like a charm. THANKS!!!

Comment: happy to help..
:)